# How to remove leading zeros using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to remove leading zeros from a number. I want to use `Integer(i)` instead of `i.to_i` in order to `rescue` nil.

```
"011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| Integer i rescue nil}
```

I want to get:

```
[11,12,nil,13,14]
```

but, instead I get this:

```
[9, 12, nil, 11, 14]
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Strings of digits, starting with a zero are by default interpreted as octal numbers. See also http://wordaligned.org/articles/octal-literals

Comment: There's no rush to select an answer. I suggest that in future you consider waiting at least a couple of hours; many here wait several hours and sometimes a day. (Sometimes never, of course.) A quick selection can discourage other answers and imo is inconsiderate to those still working on answers.

Comment: Yes cary,i will do that in future questions.(new user here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation of `Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

> **Integer(arg, base=0) → integer**

> […]
> If *arg* is a `String`, when *base* is omitted or equals zero, radix indicators (`0`, `0b`, and `0x`) are honored.
> […]

You're omitting *base* so the leading `0` in your strings means base-8 (or [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)) is used by the conversion into integers. [Integer literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) work the same way (`011 == 9` yields `true`). If those prefixes/radix indicators shouldn't be honored and the integers represented by the strings should be treated as base-10 (or [decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)) one, pass `10` for *base*:

```
"011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| Integer(i, 10) rescue nil} # => [11, 12, nil, 13, 14]
```

Or since Ruby 2.6:

```
"011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| Integer(i, 10, exception: false)} # => [11, 12, nil, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Good answer. I didn't know that `Integer` takes a second argument. I suggested @Dirk after your answer seemed to have been deleted for some reason. (Maybe I had a stale web page.)

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer('011')
=> 9
```

you can use `to_i` method

```
"011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| i.to_i rescue nil}
=> [11, 12, 0, 13, 14]

"011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| i.to_i == 0 ? nil : i.to_i}
[11, 12, nil, 13, 14]

"0,011,12,h,013,14".split(",").map{|i| (i =~ /\D/).nil? ? i.to_i : nil }
 [0, 11, 12, nil, 13, 14]
```

Comment: i want a nil returned instead of zero.

Comment: Yes ,that is what i wanted.Thanks

Comment: @owade I think cremno's answer is better.

Comment: You have answered a different question.

Comment: Yep,i have corrected the accepted answer to cremno,i was mainly interested in nil..