# How to remove leading zeros from decimal strings

Tags: ruby

Given an array of decimal values stored as strings, such as

```
["006", "025", "004", "034", "158", "019", "255", "000"]
```

how can I remove all leading zeros while preserving the values as strings to obtain

```
["6", "25", "4", "34", "158", "19", "255", "0"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strictly convert string to integer (or nil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980295/strictly-convert-string-to-integer-or-nil)

Comment: Question is a little unclear -- What is `006 025 004 034 158 019 255 000`? An array? A string? (And if so, what is the separator? A single space?)

Comment: _"I have the following output"_ – how do you generate that output? Show your code, please.

Comment: When giving an example, always show inputs and outputs as valid Ruby objects. Here, assuming they are strings, surround each with single or double quotes.  Moreover, it is helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `str = "006 025 004 034 158 019 255 000"`). That way, readers can refer to those variables (here just `str`) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: It is an array:   ["006", "025","004","034","158","019","255","000"]

Comment: Please edit the question rather than trying to clarify in a comment.

Comment: Your question still needs clarification.  Should the result be a string, an array of numbers, an array of strings, or something else entirely?

Comment: I am downvoting and voting to close because the OP has seen the comments above but has failed to edit the question to clarify what is being asked.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can I make them to be like this" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: "Also ok to convert "006" to "6", since I have them stored in a variable"  What are you trying to say here that isn't covered by your question on how to convert values inside the array?  The first part of your edit is helpful, but this muddies the waters yet again.

Comment: `["006","025","004","034","158","019","255","000"].map { |n| n.to_i.to_s }`

Comment: @SagarPandya Alternatively, `["006","025","004","034","158","019","255","000"].map { |s| s.sub(/^0+(\d)/, '\1') }`

Comment: The question is perfectly clear to me.  Note the tag is for Ruby.  Maybe an indication that Ruby is being used here.

Comment: @TayloredWebSites The question is from 2018 and has been edited multiple times since then, so it doesn't match the version that generated the comments.

Answer (score 2):

From "[Remove leading zeros Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371792/remove-leading-zeros-ruby)":

```
string = '006 025 004 034 158 019 255 000'
answer = string.split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

This returns:

```
[6, 25, 4, 34, 158, 19, 255, 0]
```

If you want to flatten that and turn it back into a string of the same format:

```
answer = answer.join(' ')
```

which leaves:

```
"6 25 4 34 158 19 255 0"
```

Comment: You could use `map(&:to_i)` for your mapping.

Comment: Good point and thanks - updated my answer

Comment: Your `split` won't work in its current form, there are no commas in the original string.  Use `split(/\s+/)` to split on one or more whitespaces, or `split(/\D+/)` for one or more non-digits of any type.

Comment: @pjs or just `.split`.

Comment: @mudasobwa `.split` won't work on something as funky as `'1  2;30 04'`.  `.split(/\D+/)` will.

Comment: Clarified my question, and tried it in my code but without luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
"006 025 004 034 158 019 255 000".gsub(/(?<= |\A)0+(?=\d)/,'')
  #=> "6 25 4 34 158 19 255 0"
```

The regular expression reads:

- Match a space or the beginning of the string in a positive lookbehind
- Match one or more zeros
- Match a digit in a positive lookahead

Comment: Some weird voting happening today. There is no reason this should be downvoted.

Comment: I posted my answer before the OP noted in a comment that the receiver is an array of strings rather than a string.

Comment: @SagarPandya: the tooltip when you hover over the downvote arrow gives guidance as to when to downvote: "this answer is not useful". Some people interpret useful to mean "useful to the [so] community", and in that sense, answers to crappy questions are not useful, since they reward anti-social (in the sense of "society" being the [so] community at large) behavior. I don't know who and why downvoted this answer, but it is one possible explanation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see, that would make sense. Though if this is the case then I wish the voter was consistent and downvoted all answers to this question.

Comment: Clarified my question, and tried it in my code but without luck

Comment: @user2909180 don't rely on luck. Take some time and follow a good tutorial where you'll gain the necessary skills to tackle these kinds of problems :)

Comment: You could also use `\b` instead of `(?<= |\A)`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I'm on the fence as to which to use. `\b` is simpler but what I have may read better.